# Adaptive algorithm for filtering gyroscope data

Tags: algorithm, filtering, gyroscope

Is there an adaptive algorithm for filtering gyroscope noise?

My app currently has a startup dialog to calibrate gyroscope, where it asks user to put the phone on the table for 5 seconds, and records min/max values of gyro data collected in these 5 seconds, then the app discards all values between that min/max, that's technically a high-pass filter.

The adaptive algorithm would determine these min/max values automatically over time, without any dialogs.

Something like storing last 100 values, and finding min/max of these values, but how do I know which values represent movement, and which are zero movement + noise?

I've looked into Kalman filter, but it's for a combined gyroscope + accelerometer sensors.

The gyroscope in my phone is not only noisy, but also has shifted zero coordinate, so when the phone is lying perfectly still, the gyroscope reports constant small rotation.

[image: Gyroscope data graph]

Comment: Note that merely ignoring low amplitude signals is not high pass filtering. That's ignoring low _frequency_ signals.  And there's nothing about Kalman filtering that prevents it from being used in this application. Look into it further. It's meant to do exactly what you're intending.

Comment: Agree about high-pass filter, my wording is incorrect. Please point me to any Kalman filter code example that involves only gyroscope and not accelerometer, because from what I've found so far, it requires both to work efficiently, and I don't care about phone's angle to the horizon, or if rotating it the exact angle back and forth will not get the same calculated angle value, I only need angles to not drift and not shake while the phone is stationary.

Comment: @pelya anyway without magnetometer angles will drift when device is rotated. Is it ok?

Comment: It is okay if angles drift during rotation, it's quite hard to notice that for the user, but drifting while device is stationary is noticeable and irritating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the piece of code I ended up with (Java, Android).
The algorithm takes very large initial values for filter range, and gradually decrease them, and it filters out movement by comparing input data to the previous filter range, and discarding 10 last measured values if it detects movement.

It works best when the phone is lying still on the table, but still works reasonably okay when the phone is moved and rotated.

```
class GyroscopeListener implements SensorEventListener
{
    // Noise filter with sane initial values, so user will be able
    // to move gyroscope during the first 10 seconds, while the noise is measured.
    // After that the values are replaced by noiseMin/noiseMax.
    final float filterMin[] = new float[] { -0.05f, -0.05f, -0.05f };
    final float filterMax[] = new float[] { 0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f };

    // The noise levels we're measuring.
    // Large initial values, they will decrease, but never increase.
    float noiseMin[] = new float[] { -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f };
    float noiseMax[] = new float[] { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };

    // The gyro data buffer, from which we care calculating min/max noise values.
    // The bigger it is, the more precise the calclations, and the longer it takes to converge.
    float noiseData[][] = new float[200][noiseMin.length];
    int noiseDataIdx = 0;

    // When we detect movement, we remove last few values of the measured data.
    // The movement is detected by comparing values to noiseMin/noiseMax of the previous iteration.
    int movementBackoff = 0;

    // Difference between min/max in the previous measurement iteration,
    // used to determine when we should stop measuring, when the change becomes negligilbe.
    float measuredNoiseRange[] = null;

    // How long the algorithm is running, to stop it if it does not converge.
    int measurementIteration = 0;

    public GyroscopeListener(Context context)
    {
        SensorManager manager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        if ( manager == null && manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) == null )
            return;
        manager.registerListener(gyro, manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(final SensorEvent event)
    {
        boolean filtered = true;
        final float[] data = event.values;

        if( noiseData != null )
            collectNoiseData(data);

        for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        {
            if( data[i] < filterMin[i] )
            {
                filtered = false;
                data[i] -= filterMin[i];
            }
            else if( data[i] > filterMax[i] )
            {
                filtered = false;
                data[i] -= filterMax[i];
            }
        }

        if( filtered )
            return;

        // Use the filtered gyroscope data here
    }

    void collectNoiseData(final float[] data)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < noiseMin.length; i++ )
        {
            if( data[i] < noiseMin[i] || data[i] > noiseMax[i] )
            {
                // Movement detected, this can converge our min/max too early, so we're discarding last few values
                if( movementBackoff < 0 )
                {
                    int discard = 10;
                    if( -movementBackoff < discard )
                        discard = -movementBackoff;
                    noiseDataIdx -= discard;
                    if( noiseDataIdx < 0 )
                        noiseDataIdx = 0;
                }
                movementBackoff = 10;
                return;
            }
            noiseData[noiseDataIdx][i] = data[i];
        }
        movementBackoff--;
        if( movementBackoff >= 0 )
            return; // Also discard several values after the movement stopped
        noiseDataIdx++;

        if( noiseDataIdx < noiseData.length )
            return;

        measurementIteration++;
        if( measurementIteration > 5 )
        {
            // We've collected enough data to use our noise min/max values as a new filter
            System.arraycopy(noiseMin, 0, filterMin, 0, filterMin.length);
            System.arraycopy(noiseMax, 0, filterMax, 0, filterMax.length);
        }
        if( measurementIteration > 15 )
        {
            // Finish measuring if the algorithm cannot converge in a long time
            noiseData = null;
            measuredNoiseRange = null;
            return;
        }

        noiseDataIdx = 0;
        boolean changed = false;
        for( int i = 0; i < noiseMin.length; i++ )
        {
            float min = 1.0f;
            float max = -1.0f;
            for( int ii = 0; ii < noiseData.length; ii++ )
            {
                if( min > noiseData[ii][i] )
                    min = noiseData[ii][i];
                if( max < noiseData[ii][i] )
                    max = noiseData[ii][i];
            }
            // Increase the range a bit, for safe conservative filtering
            float middle = (min + max) / 2.0f;
            min += (min - middle) * 0.2f;
            max += (max - middle) * 0.2f;
            // Check if range between min/max is less then the current range, as a safety measure,
            // and min/max range is not jumping outside of previously measured range
            if( max - min < noiseMax[i] - noiseMin[i] && min >= noiseMin[i] && max <= noiseMax[i] )
            {
                // Move old min/max closer to the measured min/max, but do not replace the values altogether
                noiseMin[i] = (noiseMin[i] + min * 4.0f) / 5.0f;
                noiseMax[i] = (noiseMax[i] + max * 4.0f) / 5.0f;
                changed = true;
            }
        }

        if( !changed )
            return;

        // Determine when to stop measuring - check that the previous min/max range is close enough to the current one

        float range[] = new float[noiseMin.length];
        for( int i = 0; i < noiseMin.length; i++ )
            range[i] = noiseMax[i] - noiseMin[i];

        if( measuredNoiseRange == null )
        {
            measuredNoiseRange = range;
            return; // First iteration, skip further checks
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < range.length; i++ )
        {
            if( measuredNoiseRange[i] / range[i] > 1.2f )
            {
                measuredNoiseRange = range;
                return;
            }
        }

        // We converged to the final min/max filter values, stop measuring
        System.arraycopy(noiseMin, 0, filterMin, 0, filterMin.length);
        System.arraycopy(noiseMax, 0, filterMax, 0, filterMax.length);
        noiseData = null;
        measuredNoiseRange = null;
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor s, int a)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, a very simple heuristic such as finding the mean of the data and defining a threshold that signifies true movement should both combat the offset zero coordinate and give pretty accurate peak recognition.

```
// Initialize starting mean and threshold
mean = 0
dataCount = 0
thresholdDelta = 0.1

def findPeaks(data) {
    mean = updateMean(data)

    for point in data {
        if (point > mean + thresholdDelta) || (point < mean - thresholdDelta) {
            peaks.append(point)
        }
    }
    max = peaks.max()
    min = peaks.min()

    thresholdDelta = updateThreshold(max, min, mean)

    return {max, min}
}

def updateThreshold(max, min) {
    // 1 will make threshold equal the average peak value, 0 will make threshold equal mean
    weight = 0.5

    newThreshold = (weight * (max - min)) / 2
    return newThreshold
}

def updateMean(data) {
    newMean = (sum(data) + (dataCount * mean)) / (dataCount + data.size)
    dataCount += data.size
    return newMean
}
```

Here we have a threshold and mean that will update over time to become more accurate to present data.

If you have peaks that vary quite strongly (say your largest of peaks can be quadruple the smallest) you would want to set your threshold weight accordingly (for our example, 0.25 would **just** catch the smallest of your peaks, in theory.)

**Edit:**

I think doing things like averaging your thresholds would probably make it more resistant to decay from small peaks.

```
thresholdCount = 0

def updateThreshold(max, min) {
    // 1 will make threshold equal the average peak value, 0 will make threshold equal mean
    weight = 0.5

    newThreshold = (weight * (max - min)) / 2
    averagedThreshold = (newThreshold + (thresholdCount * thresholdDelta)) / (thresholdCount + 1)
    return averagedThreshold
}
```

Comment: The question was about calculating thresholdDelta, simply using 0.1 won't do because noise levels vary greatly between devices, and even between different axes of the same gyroscope chip, and setting any fixed big value will cut down gyroscope sensitivity. So algorithm would use 0.1 as initial value, then increase or decrease it over time depending on the noise level. I don't need anything complicated, just something like adding (last noise value) * 0.05 on each iteration will work fine.

Comment: @pelya yeah that touches on what I was saying at the end. You could keep updating your threshold by simply averaging between your mean and what your algorithm predicts as peaks. Of course, to begin with this would be terribly inaccurate, but as it steadily increases it will find a true threshold. You can even weight the peak and mean components of the averaging operation differently if your noise data is extremely radical. Let me know if you want this in code.

Comment: Yes please, give me a piece of code. Wouldn't taking (peak + mean) / 2 as the next threshold cut off all peaks in the middle, discarding useful data? http://i.imgur.com/mDzIbai.jpg

Comment: @pelya Do you mean cut off the height of the peaks in the middle? Or do you mean that some of your peaks are half the size of others, so you would miss the little ones entirely?

Comment: Yes exactly, I need to only cut noise, and pass me all peaks. The peaks will vary in size, depending on how fast user will rotate the phone, some of them are 0.05 height of the others, but still above noise level. http://i.imgur.com/jDtNt7I.jpg   Your code does not use `mean` inside  `updateThreshold`, and does not update `dataCount`, could you please clean it up?

Comment: @pelya perfect, then you'll just need to set your weight to something like 0.045. Updating your threshold doesn't actually require your mean if you simplify the equation, but if you'd like I can add back in the mean and you'll see how I simplified? Cleaned up the error, thanks for the catch.

Comment: @pelya do you need any more information to accept the answer? Let me know and I'll do my best to provide.

Comment: Unfortunately this algorithm does not work when the phone is lying motionless - after working for a while, it starts treating peaks inside the noise as movement, and passes through largest parts of the noise. It works only when I'm actively moving the phone.

Comment: @pelya I think you'll need to play with your weight. It should be high enough to ignore noise, if you're picking up noise data then your weight is still too low. Otherwise, I would recommend training something like a Nearest Neighbour algorithm or perhaps even a neural network for the task.

Comment: @pelya I think an improvement might be making your threshold an average over all past thresholds.. that will probably limit the decay and make it more true to the actual. Updated my post to reflect that.